# Multiple Prefixes in discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make my discord bot have multiple prefixes but this is my code run for my `botconfig.json`

```
{
    "token":"<bot token>",
    "prefix": "p!"
}
```

what I wanted to do was have multiple prefixes: p!, P!, !p, !P, and ;

how would i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an array like:

```js
prefixes = ["p!", "!p", ";"]

//check if prefix
for(let i=0;i<prefixes.length;i++){
   if (msg.content.startsWith(prefixes[i].toLowerCase() || msg.content.startsWith(prefixes[i]).toUpperCase){
        // your code
   }
}
```

Or like what you did, you can do

```js
{
    'token' : '<token>',
    'prefixes': ['p!', '!p', ';']
}
```

Comment: i tried using an array but it didnt respond to any of my code then. using any prefix.

Comment: oh, maybe could you like show the code so that we can debug it

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this issue would be would be to check to see if the prefix used is included in the prefixes array. This would avoid the bulky `for` loop which could cause issues later on down the line as you continue to add more features to your bot. A quick example of how this could be done is as follows:

```js
const cfg = require('botconfig.json');

if(cfg.prefixes.includes(msg.content.startsWith)) {
    //Your Code
}
```